# If a Kohen donates a kidney is he considered a Bal Moom for purposes of doing an Avodah?

Tags: kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash

If a Kohen donates a kidney, is he considered a Bal Moom for purposes of doing an Avodah in the future Bais hamikdash? On the one hand, the missing organ is not visible. On the other hand, a cataract is also not visible and I think it would make a Kohen a baal moom.

Comment: Cataracts can be visible, depending on how clouded the lens has become

Comment: Some posek is going to have to study this whole question when Beit Hamikdash will be rebuilt. What about having an appendix removed or any other operation? The medical world is very different from what existed at the time of Bayit Sheni.  What if the Cohen were to _receive_ a kidney? What about dental work. Implants? Lots of possibilities to consider.

Comment: No. Apperently it isn't in the list in bechorot.

Comment: Depending on where it is, a mole with hair growing out of it isn’t visible either.

Answer (score 5):

The Rambam ([Bias Mikdash 6:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1008247/jewish/Biat-Hamikdash-Chapter-6.htm)) states clearly that a Kohain whos Kidney was removed is NOT considered a Baal Mum.

אֵין פּוֹסֵל בָּאָדָם אֶלָּא מוּמִין שֶׁבְּגָלוּי. אֲבָל מוּמִין שֶׁבַּחֲלַל הַגּוּף **[כְּגוֹן שֶׁנִּטַּל כֻּלְיָתוֹ](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1008247/jewish/Biat-Hamikdash-Chapter-6.htm)** שֶׁל אָדָם אוֹ טְחוֹל שֶׁלּוֹ אוֹ שֶׁנִּקְּבוּ מֵעָיו אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁנַּעֲשָׂה טְרֵפָה עֲבוֹדָתוֹ כְּשֵׁרָה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ויקרא כא יט) "שֶׁבֶר רָגֶל אוֹ שֶׁבֶר יָד" מָה אֵלּוּ בְּגָלוּי אַף כּל בְּגָלוּי:

Only blemishes that are apparent disqualify a person. Blemishes that are **within the cavity of the body, e.g., a person's kidney** or his spleen was removed or his intestines were perforated, even though he becomes a treifah,18 his service is acceptable. [This is derived from the mention, Leviticus 21:19, of] "a broken leg or a broken arm." Just as these are apparent, all [disqualifying blemishes] must be apparent.

The deciding factor is NOT whether it is visable or not, but rather if it is considered בַּחֲלַל הַגּוּף - within the cavity of the body.

Comment: Although the beginning of the Rambam uses the term " בגלוי" which would seem to mean visable, but from the latter part of his explanation we see that it only excludes that which is considered בַּחֲלַל הַגּוּף within the cavity of the body.